# Safe CLI Transaction - Invalid Syntax

Tags: transactions, gnosis-safe, error, safe-core-sdk, cli

I sent an nft to the wrong chain (eth) so I created a new gnosis wallet on the correct chain (optimism) with the same address.

I am now trying to send that nft using safe cli; I am using the following command line: safe-cli <checksummed_safe_address> <ethereum_node_url>

I am putting in the newly created wallet address in the first bracket and 'https://safe-transaction-optimism.safe.global' in the second bracket.

However I getting this error message:

File "", line 1
safe-cli 0x804fEf7a32213D73Aa42d0cf40BeB2Af8e7a89d7 https://safe-transaction-optimism.safe.global
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?